# How to write a regex to split a String in this format?

Tags: java, regex, string

I want to use `[,.!?;~]` to split a string, but I want to remain the `[,.!?;~]` to its place for example:

> This is the example, but it is not enough

**To**

```
[This is the example,, but it is not enough] // length=2
[0]=This is the example,
[1]=but it is not enough
```

As you can see the comma is still in its place. I did this with this regex `(?<=([,.!?;~])+)`. **But** I want if some special word (e.g: but) comes after the `[,.!?;~]`, then do not split that part of string. For example:

> I want this sentence to be split into this form, but how to do. So if
>   anyone can help, that will be great

**To**

```
[0]=I want this sentence to be split into this form, but how to do.
[1]=So if anyone can help,
[2]=that will be great
```

As you can see this part (form, but) is not split int the first sentence.

Comment: Use a negative lookahead. `(?<=[,.!?;~])(?! but)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used:

1. Positive Lookbehind `(?<=a)b` to keep the delimiter.
2. Negative Lookahead `a(?!b)` to rule out stop words.

Notice how I've appended RegEx `(?!\\s*(but|and|if))` after your provided RegEx. You can put all those stop words that you've to rule out (eg, but, and, if) inside the bracket separated by `pipe symbol`.

Also do notice that the delimiter is still in it's place.

**Output**

```
Count of tokens = 3
I want this sentence to be split into this form, but how to do.
So if anyone can help,
that will be great
```

**Code**

```
import java.lang.*;

public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "I want this sentence to be split into this form, but how to do. So if anyone can help, that will be great";
        //String delimiters = "\\s+|,\\s*|\\.\\s*";
        String delimiters = "(?<=,)";

        // analyzing the string 
        String[] tokensVal = str.split("(?<=([,.!?;~])+)(?!\\s*(but|and|if))");

        // prints the number of tokens
        System.out.println("Count of tokens = " + tokensVal.length);

        for (String token: tokensVal) {
            System.out.println(token);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks sir! That is what is want.